# Using the Insert key as a hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys

I recently started using parcellite, I love the program but can't get the shortcuts working the way I want. I want 'insert' to bring up the history menu, I tried setting it to  but it didn't work. I probably just don't know the correct name for the key.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange, worked for me.

- Right click Parcellite icon (for running program) > choose *Preferences*

  - or press `<Ctrl><Alt>P`, which should be default key combo for *Options* > choose *Preferences*
- Go to *Keyboard shortcuts* tab
- put `Insert` instead of `<Ctrl><Alt>H`
- Enjoy.

Just tested.

Comment: I was using '<Insert>' instead of just 'Insert'

Comment: The question "How to input". :-) Happens all the time, not just in Parcellite. :-)